# Unable to render custom field after attempt to generate a list of recent post in page template

Tags: php, posts, custom-field, templates, get-posts

When I try to render a list of recent post type either by using WP functions or WP query, I'm not able to render the custom fields that I have to render bit after.

The content of box with class `feat-block` ends up empty every time when using one of following commands:

```
$recent_news_posts = wp_get_recent_posts($news_post_settings); // grab post as array
$recent_news_posts = get_posts($news_post_settings); // grab post as an object
$recent_news_posts = wp_get_archives('postbypost', '5');
$recent_news_posts = $wpdb->get_results($request);
```

Why would this be?

Here's my code:

```
<div id="home-right-bottom">
    <div class="news-block home-block">
        <h2>In the News</h2>
        <div class="content">
            <?php

                $news_post_settings = array(
                    'posts_per_page'   => 5,
                    'offset'           => 0,
                    'category'         => '',
                    'category_name'    => '',
                    'orderby'          => 'date',
                    'order'            => 'DESC',
                    'include'          => '',
                    'exclude'          => '',
                    'meta_key'         => '',
                    'meta_value'       => '',
                    'post_type'        => 'post',
                    'post_mime_type'   => '',
                    'post_parent'      => '',
                    'author'           => '',
                    'post_status'      => 'publish',
                    'suppress_filters' => true
                );

                //$recent_news_posts = wp_get_recent_posts($news_post_settings); // grab post as array
                //$recent_news_posts = get_posts($news_post_settings); // grab post as an object
                //$recent_news_posts = wp_get_archives('postbypost', '5');

                global $wpdb;

                $post_limit = 5;
                $request = "SELECT ID, post_title, post_date, guid FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type='post' ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT $post_limit";
                $recent_news_posts = $wpdb->get_results($request);

                print '<ul class="recent_news">';

                foreach($recent_news_posts as $post) {
                    /*$title = $post->post_title;
                    $date = mysql2date('m.d.y', $post->post_date);
                    $url = $post->guid;*/
                    $title = $post['post_name'];
                    $date = mysql2date('m.d.y', $post['post_date']);
                    $url = $post['guid'];

                    print '<li><span class="date">' . $date . '</span> - <a href="' . $url . '">' . $title . '</a></li>';
                }

                print '</ul>';

            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This block is not rendering after running command above. If I comment above out, following is working:

```
    <?php

        //if(get_field('featured_news')):

            $feat = get_field('featured_news');
    ?>

    <div class="feat-block home-block">
        <h2>Featured News</h2>
        <div class="content">
            <?php

                if(!empty($feat[0]['news_link'])) {
                    print '<a href="' . $feat[0]['news_link'] . '">';
                }

                if(!empty($feat[0]['news_image'])) {

                    $news_image_url = $feat[0]['news_image']['url'];
                    $news_image = aq_resize($news_image_url, 300, 180, true);

            ?>
                <img src="<?php echo $news_image; ?>" alt="<?php echo $feat[0]['news_image']['caption']; ?>" class="feat_img">
            <?php
                }
            ?>
            <p><?php
                if(!empty($feat[0]['news_short_description'])) {
                    print $feat[0]['news_short_description'];
                }
           ?></p>

           <?php

            if(!empty($feat[0]['news_link'])) {
                print '</a>';
            }

           ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php

        //endif;

    ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You overwrite the global `$post` which is where that function gets the post ID from to fetch your custom field. You need to add [`wp_reset_postdata()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata) after you run other queries that use `$post`.